# Any CMS for Play Framework?

Tags: playframework-2.0

My website is using Play 2.2 with Java. Is there a content management system which works/ can be integrated with Play framework?  Magnolia is approved CMS at my organization but Play does not support Freemarker or JSP. 
Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://prismic.io is a CMS SaaS/PaaS backend that integrates into Play nicely.

What do you mean Play doesn't support freemarker?  Play can use any template engine that you can use in Java, it's trivial to use freemarker from Play.

Comment: Thanks. I shall look into it.